# How to reset a value in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have an url like :

```
?from=353&distance=&page=2
```

If I clik on a map’s track, I add or reset track to a new value. In the same time I would like to reset the page's value to zéro

```
function processTrackGeoJSON(feature, layer) {
  layer.on("click", () => {
    let search = window.location.search;
    if(search.includes("track")) {
      search = search.replace(/track=\d+/g, 'track=' + feature.properties.id);
    }
    else {
      search += (search.length === 0 ? '?' : '')+'&track='+feature.properties.id;
    }
    window.location = window.location.pathname + search;
  })
}
```

I'm trying to chaining, but ther don't work :

```
search.replace(/track=\d+/g, 'track=' + feature.properties.id).replace(/page=\d+/g, 'track=' + 0)
```

For example, I have an url like :

```
http://example.com?name=paris&from=353&distance&page=2
```

After on(click) I get a value like track=37

I would like to add this value and reset the page's value to 0 (or delete it) like

```
http://example.com?name=paris&from=353&distance=120&trak=37&page=0
```

or

```
http://example.com?name=paris&from=353&distance=120&trak=37
```

Comment: so you need to add the track params to the url with a default value if the track param doesn't exist in url is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: The function to reset the track's value work fine. But I would like to reset the page's value too in the same time

Comment: where is the pages value parameter

Comment: in the url params

Comment: check the answer, i have updated

Comment: i think the answer will work for you, if it worked for you let me know

Comment: Not exactely, I edited my ask. I would like to set the both value : track AND page

Comment: Well, @DILEEPTHOMAS showed you the way to do it for one parameter, why can't you figure out how to do it for the other parameter?

Comment: @Icepickle I know and understand how to reset on one value... but not, how I can chain the both. Otherwise, do you think I'd ask?

Comment: What you have tried in your OP is more complex than what the answer suggests. It's just getting the `track` value as well, and applying your logic to set both of them.

Comment: Ben , check the updated answer, you can use append and delete methods. as @Icepickle suggest this will be much more easier way. Let me know if it worked for you kindly accept and vote so it will be helpful for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be the better way, check this one. You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
const query = '?from=353&distance=&page=2'

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(query);

const parameterExist = searchParams.get('page');

if(parameterExist){
 searchParams.set('page', 1) // with your feature.properties.id
}else{
  searchParams.set('page', 0) // default value
}

window.history.replaceState({}, '', `${window.location.pathname}?${searchParams}`);
```

**Update to the question**

```js
const url = new URL('http://example.com?name=paris&from=353&distance=120&page=2')

const clickedTrackValue = 37;

const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

params.append('track', clickedTrackValue);
params.delete('page') // searchParams.set('page', 0)

console.log(`${url.origin}?${params}`)


// for updating the new url, use the below snippet
//window.history.replaceState({}, '', `${location.pathname}?${params}`);
```